# Pandas exported excel file reads as Zip file format

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script that utilizes pandas to perform some aggregation on a huge dataframe and after doing so It tries to export it as an Excel "xlsx" File format.

this is the last step in the process.

```
print("Exporting to Excel...")
sum_df = sum_df.set_index('products_code')
with pd.ExcelWriter(OUTPUT_FILE, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    sum_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="stocks")
print("Done!")
```

The file exports normally but whenever I try to upload it to the server, the server rejects it and reads it as a zip file instead of an xlsx file, I found a quick fix for this which is to open the file in Microsoft Excel and just hit save and exit, this seems to fix the issue. But I don't know the reason for this behavior and was looking for help to automatically save it as a valid excel file from the script directly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why not just: sum_df.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='stocks')

Comment: Why don't you type `sum_df.to_excel(OUTPUT_FILE, sheet_name="stocks")` directly? xlsx is actually is a specialized zip file.

Comment: I suspect this isn't a `pandas` issue, rather a problem with the server. .xlsx files are zip files, after all. Can you be more specific about how the server rejects the file? What server and reject in what sense?

Comment: It's a PHP/Laravel site and it returns this error: The file must be a file of type: xlsx, xlx.

I noticed that just by saving the file once in excel it's accepted, so I guess it's not the server or the site, the file being exported has an unaccepted format somehow.

Comment: As for people asking why not just use df.to_excel 

1- I wanted to have more control over the ExcelWriter Object and the engine used.
2- It seems to rise the same error anyways.

Comment: I see. I presume you've already tried using `xlsxwriter` instead of `openpyxl`? Failing that you could try to find more information by unzipping the `pandas` file before and after saving with Excel and inspecting the contents, to see if you can find the difference. The fact that Excel recognises it as an Excel file still makes me wonder about the server software.

Comment: Actually using xlsxwriter seemed to solve the issue, can you please put it as an answer to this question so that I can pick it as the correct answer?

Comment: XlsxWriter had, and fixed, an [issue like this](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/614) a few years ago where the MIME type was showing up as Zip due to a different ordering of the files within the zip file relative to Excel. However I did a quick check with the latest openpyxl and the `file` utility on macOS and it doesn't seem to have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it seems using `xlsxwriter` as the engine has solved this issue. E.g.:

```
print("Exporting to Excel...")
sum_df = sum_df.set_index('products_code')
with pd.ExcelWriter(OUTPUT_FILE, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    sum_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="stocks")
print("Done!")
```

It would be good to know what software was used on the server, if possible, in case other people encounter this issue.